# How to print pattern with number of rows input by user

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-pattern

a = ['*','#','$']
b = [1,4,7]

How can I make use of the above lists and loop to print the pattern with the required number of rows?
Here are 2 examples if the input is 5 and 10 respectively. Do not need to print the bracket on each line. Thanks.

---

Number of rows: 5

(*)

(####)

($$$$$$$)

(*)

(####)

---

Number of rows: 10

(*)

(####)

($$$$$$$)

(*)

(####)

($$$$$$$)

(*)

(####)

($$$$$$$)

(*)

Comment: Can you include what code you have already tried and where you are getting stuck?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the modulus operator (%) to iterate through `a` and `b` and repeat from the beginning of the list.

```
a = ['*', '#', '$']
b = [1, 4, 7]
rows = int(input('>>> '))
print('\n\n'.join(f'({a[i % len(a)] * b[i % len(b)]})' for i in range(rows)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply A* B and then shift A and B by 1 per Loop Iteration

Easy to implement user input

```
a = ['*','#','$']
b=[1,4,7]
b.reverse()
b = b[-1:] + b[:-1]

print(b)

for x in range(5):
  print(a[0]*b[0])
  a = a[-1:] + a[:-1]
  b = b[-1:] + b[:-1]
```